# How do I configure 2 endpoints in infinispan11

Tags: endpoint, infinispan

client1> infinispan 11(192...)

client2> NAT IP> infinispan hotrod(192...)

client2 error!!

In the previous version, two endpoints were set, and external-host=NAT IP was set for the client2 endpoint, and each socket-bind was used separately.

In infinispan 11 I want to split the socket-bind and set the endpint.

Thank you.

Comment: what error are you getting in client2? when you say `external-host=NAT IP`, do you mean the attribute in `hotrod-connector`? `<hotrod-connector name="hotrod" external-host="NAT IP" />`

Comment: thank you. 1. (11222 port) <hotrod-connector name="hotrod" external-host="192.. IP" /> 2. (11322 port) <hotrod-connector name="hotrod-2" external-host="NAT IP" /> socket- bind attribute not working. xml parse error

Answer (score 0):

```
      <socket-bindings default-interface="public" port-offset="${infinispan.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
         <socket-binding name="default" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}"/>
         <socket-binding name="default-nat" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11322}"/>
...
...
      <endpoints socket-binding="default" security-realm="default">
         <hotrod-connector name="hotrod" external-host="192...IP">
..
..
      <endpoints socket-binding="default-nat" security-realm="default">
         <hotrod-connector name="hotrod" external-host="NAT IP">
```

ParseError

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your question now. Multiple endpoints isn't possible in Infinispan 11. It will be available in Infinispan 12 ([See JIRA](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-12402)).

Currently, both clients has to use the NAT or the 192.x.x.x IP.

Answer (score 0):

Since Infinispan 10.1, we support binding to all interfaces: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-10730
You can therefore use `server.sh -b 0.0.0.0` and the clients will get the correct topology depending on the incoming interface.